# Сложности с переходом с python 2.x на python 3.x

Tags: python, кодировка, python-3.x, файлы, python-2.x

```
def _load_config(self):
    for fn in CONFIG_FILES:
        fn = os.path.expanduser(fn)
        if os.path.exists(fn):
            raw = open(fn, "rb").read().strip().decode("utf-8")
            items = [[x.strip() for x in line.split("=", 1)] for line in raw.split("\n")]
            return dict(items)
    return None
```

Есть данная функция, написана на python 2.x,возникла задача переписать на 3.
При открытии файла выбивает ошибку, я переписал данную строку вот так

```
raw = open(bytes(fn, "rb").read().strip().decode("utf-8"))
```

Дело в том что Лутца я поверхностно пробежал и чтоб разобраться что к чему уйдет еще пара дней, кто может подсказать по этому вопросу?
Пару моих вопросов:
 1. Правильно ли приводить к битам, когда работаешь с файлами(в данном случаи файл содержит только текст) и сокетом?
 2. Второй вопрос по поводу кодировки, если я по умолчанию указал кодировку

```
# encoding=utf-8
```

Нужно ли делать декодирование при открытии, если файл имеет иную кодировку?

Comment: Эм, а что по-вашему делает `bytes(fn, "rb")`?

Comment: Да, не доглядел

Comment: Укажите, какую именно ошибку выбивает. Могу предположить, что `strip` нужно выполнять на декодированной строке. Преобразование байтов (возвращенных вызовом `open().read()`) в байты допустимо, но бессмысленно.

Comment: Хотя нет, `strip` работает и на байтах.

Comment: @maximus, если у вас написано не `bytes(fn, "rb")`, вам стоит отредактировать вопрос (вроде на редактирование собственных сообщений должны быть права).

Comment: @maximus, верно ли, что если запустить отдельно эту строчку под Python2 и Python3 на конкретном `fn`, то третий выдаст ошибку (кстати, какую?), а третий - нет?

Comment: не относится к вопросу, но для конфигов, можно [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html), shlex, json модули из стандартной библиотеки использовать (чтобы не создавать свой парсер).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хорошая новость: первый пример кода, который вы привели, работает как есть как на Python 2 так и 3.

Плохая новость: все последующие примеры показывают наличие искажённого понимания с вашей стороны как с текстом в Питоне работать—это хуже чем, если бы вы ничего не знали. Например, *декларация кодировки* типа `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` наверху Питон-файла не имеет **никакого** отношения к кодировке других файлов—если вы не смотрите на **буквальные** не-ascii буквы (такие как `u"абв"`) в вашем исходном коде (`*.py` файлы), то забудьте о ней:

- если это текст во внешнем файле—она не имеет отношения
- если текст пришёл из сети—она не имеет отношения
- если текст передали как параметр в функцию—она не имеет отношения
- если значение в переменной—она не имеет отношения
- итд

> При открытии файла выбивает ошибку

Если приведённый код (`open(fn, "rb")`) не выбрасывает ошибку на Питоне 2, то этот код не будет выбрасывать ошибку на Питоне 3. То есть у вас может быть проблема с тем как `CONFIG_FILES` определяется, но сам по себе код `open(fn, "rb")` должен работать на Питоне 2 и 3 без изменений (внутренняя реализация поменялась, но снаружи это не должно быть в данном случае заметно).

Comment: Спасибо за полный ответ, да у меня не было времени полностью разобраться с работой кодировки и файлами, поэтому и задал вопрос, требовалось быстро решить проблему

Comment: @maximus: мой ответ ни в коем случае не упрёк, что вы что-то не знали (единственный глупый вопрос—это незаданный вопрос). Лучше задать вопрос, чем не ведая молча испортить систему. В тех случаях, когда необходимо быстро решить проблему, важно её не усугублять (времени новые проблемы исправлять—нет), что требует некоторого понимания сущности проблемы (в данном случае: чем текст от байт отличается ('rb' читает байты из файла) и как одно в другое в Питоне можно преобразовать (.decode() байты в текст превращает в коде)). Заблуждение, что декларация кодировки делает, не только у вас присутствует.